# UDP broadcasting signal are not received after long time.

Tags: android, ios, sockets, networking, udp

I am developing an iOS application, working based on the signals received through UDP. Application doing some operations with the signals continuously. After some long time, signal are not getting received.

Is there any chances for application go to inactive state (if it working for some long time continuously)?

Or is there any chances for not to receive UDP broadcast signals after working some long time continuously?

I am using "GCDAsyncUdpSocket" for receiving broadcast signals for iOS.

In android also am facing the same problem.